# Optimizing and Improving Plots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, optimization, plot

I'm trying to make plots describing the competitors registered for an upcoming competition. At the moment, I have a working code that makes plots, but I want to make the plots have lines instead dots and the y limits to be changed. It sounds simple enough, but I keep running into errors that I don't expect. This probably is because my code isn't very efficient.

My current data is saved into two different arrays, one which has 349 individual divisions by the 4 division characteristics: color, age, gender and weight divisions, like so:

```
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Male', u'Heavy'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Male', u'Super-Heavy'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Male', u'Ultra-Heavy'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Female', u'Rooster'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Female', u'Light-Feather'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Female', u'Feather'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Female', u'Light'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Female', u'Middle'],
[u'BLUE', u'Master 1', u'Female', u'Medium-Heavy'],
```

I then have a 349-length array with the number of competitors in each division.

My original goal was to make a mask so that it picks out the same color, age and gender division and then plot them by weight. I'd also like to make a plot that adds up all of the different age divisions for the same color and gender and has total registrants by weight in that belt color and gender.

The code doesn't like to plot against strings (for the weight divisions) so I've also made dictionaries containing the different weight divisions to be the x-axis:

```
male_adult_divisions = {"Rooster":127.0, "Light-Feather":141.5, "Feather":154.5, "Light":168.0, "Middle":181.5, "Medium-Heavy":195.0, "Heavy":208.0, "Super-Heavy":222.0, "Ultra-Heavy":235.0}
male_juvenile1_divisions = {"Rooster":107.0, "Light-Feather":118.0, "Feather":129.0, "Light":141.0, "Middle":152.0, "Medium-Heavy":163.0, "Heavy":175.0, "Super-Heavy":186.0, "Ultra-Heavy":197.0}
male_juvenile2_divisions = {"Rooster":118.0, "Light-Feather":129.0, "Feather":141.5, "Light":152.5, "Middle":163.5, "Medium-Heavy":175.0, "Heavy":186.0, "Super-Heavy":197.0, "Ultra-Heavy":208.0}
female_adult_divisions = {"Rooster":107.0, "Light-Feather":118.0, "Feather":129.0, "Light":141.0, "Middle":152.0, "Medium-Heavy":163.0, "Heavy":175.0, "Super-Heavy":186.0}
female_juvenile_divisions = {"Rooster":98.0, "Light-Feather":106.5, "Feather":116.0, "Light":125.0, "Middle":133.5, "Medium-Heavy":143.5, "Heavy":152.0, "Super-Heavy":160.5}
```

This is the code I've gotten to work so far:

```
for gender in gender_divisions:
 gender_index = numpy.where(numpy.transpose(divisions)[2] == gender)

 for age in age_divisions:
    age_index = numpy.where(numpy.transpose(divisions)[1] == age)

    if (age == "Juvenile 1 "or age == "Juvenile 2 ") and gender == "Female":
        weight_limits = female_juvenile_divisions

    elif age == "Juvenile 1 "and gender == "Male":
        weight_limits = male_juvenile1_divisions

    elif age == "Juvenile 2 "and gender == "Male":
        weight_limits = male_juvenile2_divisions

    elif gender == "Female":
        weight_limits = female_adult_divisions

    else:
        weight_limits = male_adult_divisions

    mask = numpy.intersect1d(gender_index,age_index)
    mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, exclude_absolute)

    if not mask.size:
        break

    for i,color in enumerate(belt_divisions):
        boolean_mask = numpy.zeros(len(numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))

        if color == "WHITE":
            white_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
            for x in white_mask:
                plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="white")

        elif color == "BLUE":
            blue_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
            for x in blue_mask:
                plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="blue")

        elif color == "PURPLE":
            purple_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
            for x in purple_mask:
                plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="violet")

        elif color == "BROWN":
            brown_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
            for x in brown_mask:
                plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="brown")

        else:
            black_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
            for x in black_mask:
                plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="black")


        plt.title("Competitors in %s %s Divisions"%(gender,age))
        plt.xlabel("Weight Category")
        plt.ylabel("Number of Competitors")
        plt.ylim(0,)

    plt.show()

if age != "Juvenile 1" and age != "Juvenile 2":
    if gender == "Female":
        weight_limits = female_adult_divisions
        mask = numpy.intersect1d(gender_index, exclude_absolute)

        for i,color in enumerate(belt_divisions):
            boolean_mask = numpy.zeros(len(numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))

            if color == "WHITE":
                white_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
                for x in white_mask:
                    plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="white")

            elif color == "BLUE":
                blue_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
                for x in blue_mask:
                    plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="blue")

            elif color == "PURPLE":
                purple_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
                for x in purple_mask:
                    plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="violet")

            elif color == "BROWN":
                brown_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
                for x in brown_mask:
                    plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="brown")

            else:
                black_mask = numpy.intersect1d(mask, numpy.where(color == numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
                for x in black_mask:
                    plt.plot(weight_limits[numpy.transpose(divisions[x])[3]],competitors[x], marker = "o", c="black")


        plt.title("Competitors in All %s Divisions"%(gender))
        plt.xlabel("Weight Category")
        plt.ylabel("Number of Competitors")
        plt.ylim(0,)

    plt.show()
```

When I originally tried to write this, I tried to make an index array which would pick out the divisions that I want, but for some reason, I can't get it to work.

For example, if I have `black_mask = array([343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348])`, then I try to do `divisions[black_mask]`, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c1f99913b04a> in <module>()
----> 1 divisions[black_mask]

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

So then I thought maybe I need to make boolean array to use it as a mask:

```
boolean_mask = numpy.zeros(len(numpy.transpose(divisions)[0]))
for x in black_mask:
    boolean_mask[x] = 1
```

but I got the same error, which is why I ended up going with the inefficient code above.

Then I wanted to change the y-limits on the plot. I did this by making a variable called max_ and setting it to zero. Every time the code entered one of the if statements for belt color, I put `if competitors[x]> max_: max_ = competitors[x]`, but for some reason this made *all of my plots* go blank (even when I didn't put it in the y-limits, I think).

I'd also like to make it a line graph, but because of having to put it point-by-point I haven't been able to do it.

So at the moment these are the types of plots I'm getting out:

[image: Female Competitors]

And this is what I'm trying to emulate:

[image]

Comment: I haven't read it thoroughly, so the proposition might be a bit off. 1. You should really look into pandas dataframe which are kinda make for your problem. 2. When you do this: `black_mask = array([343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348])` and then `divisions[black_mask]`; you could try: `divisions[int(black_mask[0]):int(divisions[black_mask][-1])]` which should not through an error.

Comment: @Mathieu I've never used pandas, but the documentation looks interesting, so I'll look over it and see if that would work.
As for ``divisions[int(black_mask[0]):int(divisions[black_mask][-1])]``, that gives the same error as the other two attempts.

Comment: Pandas plotting utilities are decent for rough-and-ready type of plots; if you want to make a specialised plot then it just adds another layer of complexity on top of matplotlib. Madness lies that way, OP. What does `type(divisions)` return?